# C++ DLL to be used in C program

Tags: c++, c, dll, mingw

I have a dll whose source code is written in C++ . I would like to create the static version of that library and I would like to be able to link this static library in a another library which is written in pure C. The compiler is MinGW on Windows.
How should I compile the first C++ static library so to make it usable by a C library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you plan on calling member functions of an instance of C++ class you will need to provide forwarding functions. You will also need to provide at least one function to return a pointer to an instance of the class you want to access. There are to significant reasons for this. 1) Constructors are special and do *not* have names so they cannot be called directly and 2) member functions take an implicit `this` parameter which can be passed on the stack *or* in a register.

For instance let's say you have a class called `SomeClass`

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass
{
public:
    void Print(int value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
    void Print(const char *value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
};
```

Now, you want to add a type safe way of creating and accessing an instance of that class. You can create a C interface that provides the creation function and forwarding functions. You might start by adding an additional header file to provide the C interface for `SomeClass`

> **XSomeClass.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    // C type representing SomeClass. This adds some type safety to it's use in C    
    typedef struct XSomeClass XSomeClass;

    // This will create an instance of SomeClass and return a pointer to XSomeClass
    XSomeClass* SomeClass_Create( );

    // forwarding calls to access member functions of SomeClass. These calls take
    // an explicit pointer to XSomeClass as the first parameter. self points to
    // an instance of SomeClass returned by SomeClass_Create()
    void SomeClass_PrintInt(XSomeClass* self, int value);
    void SomeClass_PrintString(XSomeClass* self, const char *value);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now you need to provide an implementation of the C interface. This is where all the magic happens that allows you to call C++ member functions from C.

> **XSomeClass.cpp**

```
extern "C" XSomeClass* SomeClass_Create()
{
    return reinterpret_cast<XSomeClass*>(new SomeClass());
}

extern "C" void SomeClass_PrintInt(XSomeClass* self, int value)
{
    reinterpret_cast<SomeClass*>(self)->Print(value);
}

extern "C" void SomeClass_PrintString(XSomeClass* self, const char *value)
{
    reinterpret_cast<SomeClass*>(self)->Print(value);
}
```

I recommend using `reinterpret_cast` over C style casts to prevent the accidental removal of `const` qualifiers.

To access the C++ library from C you can now do something like the example below

> **main.c**

```
#include "XSomeClass.h"

int main(int, char**)
{
    XSomeClass *sc = SomeClass_Create();
    SomeClass_PrintInt(sc, 1);
    SomeClass_PrintString(sc, "hello");
}
```

<sub>**Note:** Simply putting the C++ library in a DLL and calling `GetProcAddress` for free functions and static member functions will be difficult as you will need to take into account [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You add a C API to your C++ library. In the header file you add

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
.
.
.
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

You do the same in your C api C++ file "but you can leave out the `#ifdef`s because you know you will be compiling them using your C++ compiler.

You C api C++ file then can access the C++ API but your library is guaranteed to export using the C style Application Binary interface (no name mangling). The library can then be used from a C application.

The header file will be good to go both in C and C++ projects

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by "You do the same in your C api C++ file "but you can leave out the #ifdefs because you know you will be compiling them using your C++ compiler"

Comment: you will need to add the extern "C" { ... } stuff in. You just don't need the #ifdefs. The idea is that you compile with a C++ compiler but your functions get exported with a C ABI so they can be used in a C program.

Comment: You might be also required to write thin interface layer, e.g. if your c++ function might throw exception this exception would be fatal to your host C program. Write a tiny extern "C" C++ function that catches all exception and return appropriate error code. If your C++ library's interface deals with objects, introduce obscure handles for them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, you do the opposite.  You make the C library work in your C++ program.  C++ encompasses C, not the other way around (superset C++, subset C).  So what you do, is you can write a C++ program (using C++ or C syntax), and compile this program with a c++ compiler.  You can then use C and C++ libraries.

Comment: What if I compile the C++ library as a DLL and then use it by calling from the C library through LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress? It should work right?

Comment: Yes, it will work.  Just make sure you reference the library in your c++ library and link them together.

Comment: this is not true, you can easily use C++ library from C program as long as the library provides C interface

Comment: In some cases, this is not possible, e.g. if there is a considerable existing codebase written in C, that needs to be extended with new functionality (which is to be written in C++).