# Way to use common class between C style exporting API in C++ DLL

Tags: c++, c, dll, global-variables, dllexport

I'm writing C++ library and now design C style API for it. For now I have bunch of methods that uses singleton of main class, here simplified declaration:

```
extern "C" {
    MYDLL_API void getAudioDeviceList();
    MYDLL_API void getWindowList();

    MYDLL_API uint32_t BeginVideoCapture();
    MYDLL_API uint32_t StopVideoCapture();
}
```

But so far I decided to remove singletons, there the dilemma. What is most elegant way to use my class through API calls? For now I see only one way, using global variable and init method, like (where CVideoConverter it's C struct wrap under C++ class):

```
extern "C" {
    CVideoConverter* t = new CVideoConverter();

    MYDLL_API void getAudioDeviceList();
    MYDLL_API void getWindowList();

    MYDLL_API uint32_t BeginVideoCapture();
    MYDLL_API uint32_t StopVideoCapture();
}
```

Or should I create some C struct that will contain all API methods and pointer to CVideoConverter object, that export struct itself. Waiting for your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: To help you, we need more details about the link between your `class CVideoConverter` and DLL functions. How did you use the `DllMain()` entry point and `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` / `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a global variable in a header file is never going to lead to happiness. Instead if you want a C API for your C++ code, I recommend you actually look at the `FILE` and standard C file handling functions.

The `FILE` type-alias is an *opaque structure*, you don't know its contents and neither should you care. Instead you have a function which allocates an instance of your opaque structure and returns a pointer to it. Then all your C API functions takes this pointer as an argument.

What this opaque structure really is? It doesn't really matter, it could simply be a private structure containing an instance of your main class. Then the C API functions which have the full definition of the structure and the classes) can use it to call the member functions needed.

---

A small and simple example:

The ***public*** header file, which is what the C applications should include:

```
#ifndef MY_C_API_H
#define MY_C_API_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Forward declaration of the MYSTRUCT structure, and definition of type-alias
typedef struct MYSTRUCT MYSTRUCT;

MYSTRUCT *my_create(void);
void my_destroy(MYSTRUCT *mystruct);
void my_do_something(MYSTRUCT *mystruct, int some_argument);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // End of header include guard
```

The ***private*** header file, to be used internally by your application only:

```
#ifndef MY_PRIVATE_H
#define MY_PRIVATE_H

#include "my_c_api.h"
#include "my_class.h"

struct MYSTRUCT
{
    MyClass my_object;
};

#endif
```

The implementation of the C API:

```
#include "my_private.h"

extern "C"
{
    MYSTRUCT *my_create(void)
    {
        return new MYSTRUCT;
    }

    void my_destroy(MYSTRUCT *mystruct)
    {
        delete mystruct;
    }

    void my_do_something(MYSTRUCT *mystruct, int some_argument)
    {
        mystruct->my_object.do_something(some_argument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One good approach (not the only one), is to provide an instance factory function of your class `CVideoConverter` which will return a transtyped C instance via `reinterpret_cast`. This way, you can call your C exported function by providing this instance reference as 1st parameter. On DLL side, you retranstype into C++ instance and call your instance's method.

Please follow this link which provide more detailed explanations and very good examples.

[C++ DLL to be used in C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575060/c-dll-to-be-used-in-c-program)